# ngRepeat doesn't display items

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

We're working on a e-commerce platform at my work and we use AngularJS. Yesterday we put a great amount (200+, in small quantities it works well) of products in the bag and a bug started, some items aren't listed but **it is** in the HTML when we inspect elements.

The following codes are what we have:

**The directive:**

```
class dSacolaItem{

constructor(){

    this.restrict = 'EA';
    this.templateUrl = 'views/directives/component-sacola-item.html';

    this.scope = {
        dirParent: '=?dSacolaItem'
    };
}}
```

**The template of the items:**

```
<div class="row block-item" ng-repeat="(key, prod) in dirParent.data track by $index">

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6">
    <div class="box-img pull-left">
        <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="images/photos/50/{{::prod.imagem}}" d-err-src="images/photos/50/0.jpg" alt="{{::prod.descricao_curta}}">
    </div>

    <div class="box-infos pull-left">
        <h5 class="text-uppercase text-primary" ui-sref="main.produto({ idproduto: {{::prod.id_produto}}, descricao: '{{::prod.descricao_link}}' })">{{::prod.descricao_curta}}</h5>
        <small>{{::prod.var1 == undefined ? 'Único' : prod.var1}} | {{::prod.var2 == undefined ? 'Único' : prod.var2}} | {{::prod.var3 == undefined ? 'Único' : prod.var3}}</small>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button" ng-click="dirParent.removeItem(prod.id_variacao)">
            <span ng-show="dirParent.removing_prod != prod.id_variacao">remover</span><span ng-show="dirParent.removing_prod == prod.id_variacao"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-1 text-center">
    <div class="box-gift text-center">
        <form name="fGift" ng-submit="false" novalidate>
            <label class="gift-prod" ng-if="::(dirParent.configs.produto_preco_presente > 0)">
                <input type="checkbox" name="presente" ng-model="prod.presente" ng-change="dirParent.setGift( key, prod.presente )">
                <div>
                    <i class="fa fa-gift fa-3x"></i>
                    <small>PRESENTE</small>
                    <small>(R$ {{::dirParent.configs.produto_preco_presente | currency: '': 2}})</small>
                </div>
            </label>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-1 text-center">
    <div class="box-qtde" tooltip-placement="left" uib-tooltip="Em estoque: {{::prod.estoque}}" tooltip-enable="prod.estoque == prod.qtde">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="dirParent.updateQtde('decrement', key)" ng-class="{'disabled': prod.qtde == 1}"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="dirParent.updateQtde('increment', key)" ng-class="{'disabled': prod.estoque == prod.qtde}"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control text-center" type="text" ng-value="prod.qtde" disabled="disabled">
        <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin refresh-qtde" ng-style="dirParent.value_load[key]"></i>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 box-values text-center">
    <span>unitário:</span>
    <h5 class="text-primary">R$ {{::prod.preco | currency: '': 2}}</h5>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 box-values text-center">
    <span>total:</span>
    <h5>R$ {{prod.preco * prod.qtde | currency: '': 2}}</h5>
</div>
```

I tried to use one-time binding in every place that was possible, but some data needs to be updated...

**And finally, how I call the directive:**

```
<div class="shopping-items" d-sacola-item="bag"></div>
```

I tried to put infinite scroll but it didn't work and also went through a lot of articles trying to fix this but nothing helped.

Some prints of the problem (look to the scroll)

[Begin of displayed data (scroll is in 1/3 of the page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P76Zi.png)

[Item not displayed but in the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3nuf.png)

Anyone with the same problem? I don't know anymore what I should do to fix it.

---

[add 1]: It seems only browsers that use chromium (Chrome, Opera...) have the issue. Firefox, IE, edge and *wow* safari 5.1 (2012 version) show everything with some hard work, but at least they display data correctly.

Comment: We found that it was caused by using will-change in a general way in css.